# Safely post last task to Handler before quitting its thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I've got a background Handler and associated HandlerThread.

```
val handlerThread = HandlerThread("my background thread").apply { start() }
val handler= Handler(handlerThread)
```

When exiting the lifecycle of this class, I want to clean up something in the background thread. So I post a runnable to clean it up, and then call `handlerThread.quitSafely()`:

```
fun onDestroy() {
    handler.post {
        someObject.release()
    }
    handlerThread.quitSafely()
}
```

But I get the LogCat warning "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread", and `someObject.release()` is never called.

`quitSafely()` is supposed to stop the thread only after all messages have been processed, but not delayed messages. Looking into the source code, I see that `handler.post` posts the runnable with a delay of 0, so I guess that means it's not yet in the queue and `quitSafely()` won't wait for it to post?

What's the correct way to run one more clean-up runnable in the background thread before it's released? Could it be as simple as wrapping `handlerThread.quitSafely()` in a runnable and posting it to the main handler at the end of the background cleanup runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, and it seems to work fine.

```
fun onDestroy() {
    handler.post {
        someObject.release()
        handlerThread.quitSafely()
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're supposed to call `HandlerThread.quitSafety()`... from the `HandlerThread`? I must admit, I was hoping there was a better explanation for this issue... ☹